# How to rerun useEffect that depended on the object whose properties I do not know it's attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

I wanted to rerun useEffect if the object value changed. And when I searched, I found the solution to use (useMemo) because an object is a reference and a solution like this.

```
    // We want to rerun useEffect if name or age are changed
    const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
    
    /* 
    We need useMemo because
    if person = {age: age, name: name}
    this will make useEffect rerun even if darkMode is changed,
    and We don't want that so we will use useMemo
    */
    const person = useMemo(() => {
        return { age: age, name: name };
      }, [age, name]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect run');
      }, [person]);
    
    // or
    /*
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect run');
      }, [person.age, person.name]);
    */
```

If I don't know the attribute of person object. How can make useEffect rerun depend on the attribute of person object?

I have two suggestions, and I don't know if they are the best way or not

```
    // suggestion1 (using useMemo like that)
    const personValues = Object.keys(person).map((att) => person[att]);

    const personMemo = useMemo(() => {
        return { ...person};
      }, [...personValues ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect run');
      }, [personMemo]);
```

```
    // suggestion2 (don't use useMemo)
    const personValues = Object.keys(person).map((att) => person[att]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect run');
      }, [...personValues]);
```

I tried to spread the attribute of the person object inside useEffect's dependency array, I think this is a good way for that and I want to know if there is a better way or not

Comment: You may not want to have an object with uncertain attributes as dependencies, please check the beta docs for more info: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies